# MySQL Date/Time Functions and Timezone Issue

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I'm working on an application that uses created_at and updated_at columns in MySQL tables.  The server/system timezone is set to EDT.

Upon INSERT, I'm using the MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function for the created_at value.  MySQL automatically updates the updated_at value whenever he record is updated (ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).  My problem is that the created_at value is entered as UTC and the updated_at value is entered as EDT.

Can someone please help with a fix and explanation of this issue?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you with a fix because you've not shown any code. Mysql date, time and date time values have no concept of a timezone. Timestamp values use UTC. It is up to you to write your code to deal with these constraints. If your data will always be constrained to a single timezone then just cast any timestamp values to that timezone:

```
 SELECT CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'GMT', 'EDT'), updated_at
 FROM your_table
```

This gets very messy when you start to use more than one timezone - a better solution is to *always* store times in UTC and change the representation at the front end (but this can be a bit of a pain if you run on brain damaged operating systems or don't control the server config)

Comment: This is partially incorrect. TIMESTAMP values are automatically converted into the timezone set via the`time_zone` setting. This can be changed globally or per-session.